# Postgres Find Change In Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with survey type data that looks like this:

| responder | date | response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mary | 2021-07-15 | yes |
| lucy | 2021-07-01 | no |
| mary | 2021-06-05 | maybe |
| lucy | 2021-06-05 | yes |

How can I find a count of how many people's response has changed to a specific response later in time. The response of interest would be the most recent response. So for the respondents who have multiple responses, how could I count the number of nos that later changed to yess and so on. Thanks!

Comment: What results would you want?  Does no-->maybe-->yes count?

Comment: Something like a count of the same responders that moved from maybe to yes. In the sample, it would be a count of one for mary who changed from maybe (earlier date) to yes (later date).

Comment: Please be more specific what to count exactly. You start with a requirement and end with a different one. Also disclose your Postgres version and table definition showing data types and constraints. It matters where duplicates or NULL values are allowed.

Comment: @Erwin, the what to count is the number of times the same respondent (say mary = mary) has an older entry via the date column, and the value in the response column has changed from no to yes. In the actual data there are many duplicate responders and no NULL values. I'm only interested in the duplicate responders. The responders are stored as BIGINT, date is DATE, and response is TEXT.

Comment: @JB: That clarifies quite a bit. The information should go into the question (ideally as `CREATE TABLE` script), [edit] it. Also: only where the *final* answer is 'yes', or does any 'yes' count if there was a previous 'no'? How many duplicates are there on avg? If there are many, is there an additional table with distinct responder entries?

Comment: BTW, mary changed from 'maybe' to 'yes', not from 'no'. So your objective is still not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of nos that change to yes, you can summarize when the first no and last yes occurs.  Then aggregate:

```
select count(*)
from (select responder,
             min(date) filter (when response = 'no') as no_date,
             max(date) filter (when response = 'yes') as yes_date
      from t
      group by responder
     ) r
where no_date < yes_date;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That gives me: syntax error at or near "when"

Comment: @JB: s/when/where. But 2x `min()` seems incorrect, too.

Comment: @JB . . . What version of Postgres are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This counts how many responders changed from 'no' to 'yes':

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT responder)
FROM   survey s
WHERE  response = 'yes'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM survey s1
   WHERE  s1.responder = s.responder
   AND    s1.response = 'no'
   AND    s1.date < s.date
   );
```

The query might be optimized depending on your exact table definition and data distribution. If `(responder, response)` is defined `UNIQUE`, we can just `SELECT count(*) ...` instead.

If there are *many* duplicates, other query techniques are faster.

Alternative (similar to Gordon's query, but correct):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT FROM survey
   GROUP  BY responder
   HAVING min(date) FILTER (WHERE response = 'no') 
        < max(date) FILTER (WHERE response = 'yes')
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c53b911e368a66bbc9d5ff6146b22e64)*